# Why is cross-entropy increasing with accuracy?

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, cross-entropy

I'm making an implementation of the softmax regression and I'm struggling to understand the nature behind the problem of increasing value of Cross-Entropy: $H(y_i, p_i)=-\sum_{i=1}^C y_i log(p_i)$, along with an increasing accuracy:

[image]

This is utmost confusing to me, because there's no class imbalance:

[image]

I am not entirely sure whether the **sample size** of $N = 112$ (at the very least I cannot prove it) is at fault. I will appreciate any help on the matter. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the accuracy on your training or test data? Maybe you only have 112 samples, are training on all, and evaluating on them? To know if it is the data, or a bug in your code, I'd be looking at the confusion matrix, and maybe the individual predictions it is making. And test the code on very small artificial data sets, with no noise: accuracy should quickly go to 1.0.